# Can I trigger a command when the status bar shows up or hides?

Tags: autocmd, statusline, scrolling

I'm using `set laststatus=1` so the status bar is only visible when needed, e.g. to display file names when multiple splits are open. However, when the status bar shows up, the existing buffer seems to scroll up by one line to make space for it. When the status bar hides, it scrolls down by one line again. Is there a way to bind an `autocmd` or similar to these events to show to compensate for the apparent scrolling with a `<c-y>` on show and `<c-e>` on hide?